# AWS CodePipline & Codebuild - How to add environment variables to the Docker-Image?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, deployment, environment-variables

thx for any help.

I'm using AWS-CodePipline with AWS-CodeBuild(for my Dockerfile and save it in ECR). So far it is working. But I don't get how I get my environment variables in the project. So I connected my Github account with CodePipline and I didn't pushed my envs to Github for security. So now I have on Github a env-file like:

```
config/prod.env

ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET=
CSRF_TOKEN_SECRET=
ACCESS_TOKEN_PASSWORD=
REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET=
CLUDINARY_API=
CLUDINARY_API_SECRET=
CLUDINARY_API_NAME=
GOOGLE_AUDIENCE=
ORIGIN=
GOOGLE_TOKEN=
DATABASE_URL=
NODE_ENV=
FORGOTTEN_PASSWORD=
YAHOO_PASSWORD=
```

Now on AWS-CodeBilder is a section for environment variables(Image from AWS-Doc). [image]

Now I have the feeling this is not the right place for env's. Because if I put all my variables inside the fields I get the error:

```
ValidationException
1 validation error detected: Value at 'pipeline.stages.2.member.actions.1.member.configuration' failed to satisfy constraint: Map value must satisfy constraint: [Member must have length less than or equal to 1000, Member must have length greater than or equal to 1]
```

On Example:

```
Name: ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
Value: My_SUPER_PASSWORD
```

If I'm using just a few variables I don't get an error but for all variables I get the error(dosen't matter of the env-combination).
What I'm doing wrong? How can I get my env-variables to my Docker-Image in ECR with CodeBuild & CodePipline?

Comment: What is your code that produces the error you reported?

Comment: I'm getting the error in aws if I put my variables in the environment variables section at CodeBuild.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass variables from Code Build Project, you need to set env: section in buildspec.yml file, for example

```
env:
  variables:
    Execution_ID: $Execution_ID
    Commit_ID: $Commit_ID
```

Comment: Thx for your answere but where do you define $Execution_ID and $Commit_ID?

Comment: In Code Build Project, as you did